# Malicious Editing

Tags: discussion

A [more experienced user](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/11175/jonsca) keeps editing [my question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/104002/110894) to remove what I believe is a relevant example, presumably from political malice. His comment on my question: "Let me be a bit more curt. That's not at all ... welcome here."

How can a user who doesn't even have 2000 points yet have so much power on a platform that's passed out of beta?

Is the example provided not appropriate for my question?

Comment: That's not just a user, that's an elected Moderator. That said, if you believe this is an overreach of Moderator privileges, you can take your case to the Community Manager team. More details: [What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused his/her privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28867/21960)

Comment: @ale Thanks, I will do that.

Answer (score 11):

There was no political intent here. If at all, I took a very apolitical stance and removed something that was not germane to the question at all.

A reference was made to a Twitter profile of a figure that is...controversial in many circles.  Since it added nothing of value to the post, and *could* be construed as inflammatory/offensive/inappropriate, I removed it.  You placed it back in, and I locked the post to prevent a "rollback" war. Frankly, the details regarding your fear of being kicked off Twitter didn't add anything of value either, especially to those who will be looking for answers to your question in the future, but since their inclusion offered some objective context, I left it in.

I'm an elected moderator, and I certainly don't speak for Stack Overflow in any way, shape, or form.  I made a call as to whether this was something that violated the ["Be Nice"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice) policy (and was initially very patient and politely explained that it wasn't relevant, but perhaps should have delineated why in a more articulate fashion), and I opted to put a one day hold on the content of the question so that it didn't turn into a spectacle.

All of us might not agree on the weight of such a matter, but I erred on the side of caution here and took any trace of politics (in an abstract sense) out of a place where it really doesn't belong.

Comment: I concur. If I'd come across that post I probably would have edited it in the same way. Linking to a controversial Twitter profile when that's not germane to the question also seems a bit promotional. I could argue that the whole "I'm afraid I'm going to get kicked off Twitter" stuff is a bit unnecessary too. It's a left-handed "look at me" call. Wanting to save ones stuff from a third-party site is a sufficient reason, whether it's to protect it from the site going out of business, an account hack, a site being sold/merged, or whatever.

Answer (score 9):

As the other answers here suggest, the bit of text that was removed is completely superfluous to the question. We try to make questions on the 
Stack Exchange network relevant to others, so personal anecdotes and other bits of nonessential contextualization are often removed from posts. The text that was removed from your post fits into that group, and the question would work just fine without the justification of *why* you regularly grab the archive of your tweets:

> I regularly grab an archive of my tweets from Twitter. However, the regular archive does not include images I have uploaded to Twitter. How can I get an archive that includes the images along with the tweets?

Not only does the bit of text that you insist on editing into the question pull away from its main focus, but your engaging in an edit war does so even more, and that's what's ["not at all necessary nor welcome here"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/104002/photos-in-twitter-archive#comment90892_104002): engaging in an edit war with a moderator who had just performed a mundane routine edit, in particular to continuously make an effort to make sure an unnecessary reference to a clearly controversial figure is present in your question. **Please don't do it again.**

Note that if the notion of other people editing the content you contribute with makes you feel uncomfortable, then maybe this is not the right place for you.

Answer (score 5):

> How can a user who doesn't even have 2000 points yet have so much power on a platform that's passed out of beta?

In this case the user is also a moderator. Notice the `♦` at the end of the user's name. For all SE sites, the symbol indicates a moderator. The power of a moderator exceeds anything they could have based on reputation points alone. That authority is given to them so they can do their jobs on the site(s) they are responsible for. BTW, a moderator on one site is not necessarily one on another, and probably isn't because of the work involved in doing moderation.

> Is the example provided not appropriate for my question?

I can't say if it is appropriate or not. I can say that it *is* unnecessary. I read, and understood the question clearly without the disputed text. I also don't know why that text, on Twitter, would lead to you being kicked off. Maybe it means something, but I don't know what, since I don't use Twitter, at all.

A different, possible, problem is that the same syntax is used on all SE sites to bring the attention of the named user to that post. So it looks like you're trying to get the attention of a specific user in the question, which *is* inappropriate, even though I don't think it works in questions anyway.

Almost all the comments have been removed from the question, if there were any, so I don't know what has been said before. I'm going to guess that the moderator and yourself have exchanged words over that edit, more than once, and that the moderator has explained why the edit was done. What can be see in the comments is that the moderator thought the removed text was 1) distracting from your point, and 2) neither necessary nor welcome on this site.

I can't address the "welcome" point, but I can the other two points.

- It is ***not*** necessary. As I already explained above, without that in the question, I totally understood the question, and the potential reason for the need.
- It ***does*** distract from your question. After I reviewed the edits to see what was removed, I forgot about the question itself, and I was even distracted from this question, until I noticed this tab still open in my browser. I was thinking about "what does that mean?", "why would that get Twitter upset?", and "why doesn't the moderator like it?" The need to archive the images was gone from my mind completely. If you want a quality answer to the question, the question should only give the needed information, and the real statement of the question or problem. Honestly event the point "*I'm a little paranoid that I'll be kicked off the platform at some point*" is pointless. Why you want the archive is none of my business, and doesn't affect how you get them, so why include it in the question.

There's my 2¢ worth. Keep the change.

Comment: Actually no comments have been deleted.